# How do I set timezone for my docker container?

Tags: sql-server, docker, timezone, dockerfile

I'm using Docker 19.03 on Mac but it would be nice if there is a cross-platform solution.  I have this Dockerfile ...

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
  
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

ENV TZ=EDT
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN date
...
```

This does not seem to be doing the job of setting my timezone, because what prints out displays "EDT" but is still showing UTC time

```
 ---> d8cf39550832
Step 4/13 : ENV TZ=EDT
 ---> Running in 8996c46391f4
Removing intermediate container 8996c46391f4
 ---> e01cb9586f4c
Step 5/13 : RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
 ---> Running in 1972412de76f
Removing intermediate container 1972412de76f
 ---> fffba690cf2b
Step 6/13 : RUN date
 ---> Running in 9921f49b5353
Tue Jul 28 20:15:57 EDT 2020
```

When this was run, actual Eastern Standard time was 16:15:57.  What's the proper way to set time zone to Eastern standard?  I also tried "America/New_York" but did no better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL Server image is based on Ubunutu 16.04 (according to [its DockerHub reference page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server)).  According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40234847/634824), there's a bug in Ubuntu 16.04 with setting the time zone.

Try changing your docker file to:

```
ENV TZ=America/New_York
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

You definitely should be setting `America/New_York`, not `EST` or `EDT`.

Comment: I had to run "RUN apt-get install tzdata" before I put in your commands but then the date did display as New York time.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  I'd think `tzdata` would have been installed already in the base image - but good to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>`RUN apt-get install tzdata` is redundant. You can use `EST5EDT`.</s>

**EDIT:** Although apparently this *does the job*, please check the subtle implication of using `EST5EDT` instead of `America/New_York` in @Matt Johnson-Pint's comment below.
*Thanks for pointing this up Matt.*

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
  
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

ENV TZ=EST5EDT
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN date
```

```
Step 6/6 : RUN date
 ---> Running in 6e270d42ef56
Tue Jul 28 17:03:26 EDT 2020
```

Comment: `EST5EDT` will not have the full history of US Eastern Time that is in the tzdb.  It should be `America/New_York`.

Comment: I will remove the answer. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I have read this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950640/13736525) and I understand that an event like this - _European Parliament voted in favor of removing Daylight Saving Time (DST)_ - would not be historically tracked by the UTC+1 but it would be by CET. However, I don't understand how would this affect a computer system from the practical point of view. May I ask this question in a different post or have you answered it already somewhere else? Thank you!

Comment: That's a bit broad of a question.  There are *many* scenarios where having an accurate representation of local time changes will matter.  For example, scheduling an appointment.